# System not reaching 100% CPU how to trouble shoot

Tags: c++, performance, architecture, profiling

I have a application (basically C++ application) which has below properties

- Multi Threaded
- Each thread has its own thread attributes (like stack size, etc).
- Multi process (i.e will run multiple process).
- Run on a 8 core processor.
- Uses shared memory/IPC's/extensive heap management (allocation/deallocation), system sleep etc.

So now, I am supposed to find the system CAPS at max CPU. The ideal way is to load the system to 100% CPU and them check the CAPS (successful) the system supports.

I know, that in complex systems, CPU will be "dead" for context switches, page swaps, I/O etc.
But my system is max able to run at 95% CPU (not more than that irrespective of the load). So the idea here is to find out these points which is really contributing to "CPU eating" and then see if I can engineer them to reduce/eliminate the unused CPU's.

**Question**

1. How do we find out which IO/Context switching... etc is the cause of the un-conquerable 5% CPU? Is there any tool for this? I am aware of OProfile/Quantify and vmstat reports. But none of them would give this information.
2. There may be some operations which I am not aware - which may restrict the MAX CPU utilization. Any link/document which can help me in understanding a detailed set of operation which will reduce my CPU usage would be very helpful.

**Edit 1:**
Added some more information
a. The OS under question is SUSE10 Linux server.
b. CAPS - it is the average CALLS you can run on your system per second. Basically a telecommunication term - But it can be considered generic - Assume your application provides a protocol implementation. How many protocol calls can you make per second?

Comment: you really expect to be able to make the cpu at 100% all the time?

Comment: Q1. Which OS? This question is going to have to be OS-specific I think. Q2: What is "CAPS"? Google didn't give me a clear answer. (I couldn't work out if it is just slang for capabilities, or if it is something-something per second.)

Comment: @UmNyobe: No, the idea is to try to extract maximum CPU utilization - may be around 97-98 percent and benchmark my system capability under max load.

Comment: You mention shared memory so presumably you are using some form of lock to control access?

Comment: @JohnB: Yes I agree, the I am using many locks,unlocks. Thread context switching happens etc. But my questions is - how do I know the consumption of these activities, so that It would help me as a feedback in re-engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"100% CPU" is a convenient engineering concept, not a mathematical absolute. There's no objective definition of what it means. For instance, time spent waiting on DRAM is often counted as CPU time, but time spent waiting on Flash is counted as I/O time. With my hardware hat on, I'd say that both Flash and DRAM are solid-state cell-organized memories, and could be treated the same.

So, in this case, your system is running at "100% CPU" for engineering purposes. The load is CPU-limited, and you can measure the Calls Per Second in this state.

Comment: Though did not complete answer my question, it provided a valuable insight. So voted it as answer!